# Tailwind class doesn't take effect

Tags: css, reactjs, webpack, tailwind-css

I created a react setup for a little project and decided to add tailwind. It was successful but when I add the class to the components, I don't see any change.

This is the [link](https://github.com/dhatGuy/library/tree/react-library) to the repository

Comment: Do you get any errors? By the way, adding some code about the implementation and use of the library would help to answer it

Comment: Where are you importing `tailwind.css` into your app?

Comment: No errors so far. After adding tailwind configuration, the default styling of the library takes effect but adding class name doesn't work.

Comment: I only imported main.css in the `index.js` file. Am I to import tailwind.css too?

Comment: @Odunsi yes, you need to import `tailwind.css` as well.

Comment: Still the same. No changes

Comment: @Odunsi have you look at the example on how to integrate with with `webpack`? https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation/#build-tool-examples

Comment: @goto1 Yes, I have. My configuration is the same with it

Comment: Unless you updated your code, I don't see that setup in your repo.

Comment: Okay, I just pushed my latest commit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the problem. It was from my webpack config for CSS loader. I noticed when I added my own stylesheet, not all the rules were applied.

```
{
        loader: "css-loader",
        options: {
          modules: true,
          importLoaders: 1,
          sourceMap: true
        }
      }
```

I had to remove all the options. I don't even know why I added it at first. Tailwind CSS now works.

Comment: ok. And why do you use webpack? I suggest using react-scripts npm package which comes with create-react-app. 
https://create-react-app.dev/docs/getting-started/#get-started-immediately

Comment: Yes, I know about create-react-app. But CRA comes with some things I probably won't need. And the project I'm working on isn't large, that is why I decided to create the React app without CRA.

Answer (score 4):

Everything seems fine. Once delete the node modules and package.lock.json file and install node modules then start the server.

Also, there is no need to import tailwind.css in App.js.
Just main.css is enough as we are already appending all the styles to main.css (check scripts in package.json)

Comment: I did that and the issue still persist. I'm sure I did everything correctly. I'll just style it myself. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

If you know that you've configured Tailwind and added the right settings and presets, maybe you need to add this:

```
module.exports = {
  content: [
    './public/index.html', <-
  ],
}
```

or this, if you're using ReactJS:

```
module.exports = {
  content: [
    './pages/**/*.{html,js}',
    './components/**/*.{html,js}'
  ],
  // ...
}
```

Within your `tailwind.config.js` file.

You also can *`learn/read`* more about it on: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration, that worked perfectly for me!